# CKeditor: change default select option in dialog

Tags: javascript, select, dialog, ckeditor

I changle "Link" dialog window. Need to be able insert only anchor (remove url and emails option). I use this code:

```js
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    if ( dialogName == 'link' ) {
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
        var linktypeField = infoTab.get( 'linkType' );        
        linktypeField['default'] = 'anchor';
        linktypeField['items'].splice(0, 1);
        linktypeField['items'].splice(1, 1);        
    }
});
```

This code remove url and email options. But when the dialog box appears nothing is selected. How to select "anchor" option by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your customisation is OK, except it's missing:

```
linktypeField.setup = function() {
    this.setValue( 'anchor' );
};
```

because default implementation selects `url` link type when creating a new link, unless `data` (link selected in editor contents) says different:

```
setup: function( data ) {
    this.setValue( data.type || 'url' );
},
```

[See the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oleq/z9ebo6k8/).